# why android app icon showing twice after installing from Play store but only once via simulator

Tags: android, mobile, icons

im new to native android app dev and so wanted to ask for some advice here. situation is that when our companies app is downloaded from the Play store - you will see 2 x app icons on device.

however - if i build/install via Android Studio to both device and simulator - i only see one app icon.

ive dug around and found advice that says check the AppManifest.xml and ensure that there is only a single ocurrance of this block:

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

I've confirmed that there is only one instance.

So where else should I be looking to see why the dupe icons are showing via the Play store installs ? Or is it, that since the simulator and physical device via Android Studio are OK - we should be fine and just need to wait until the next app update to the Play store ?

any advice on this would be greatly appreciated, cheers.

**EDIT: Here's the manifest (Application segment)**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="xxxxxx">

    <!-- Splash Screen Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="xxxxx"
        android:label="@string/app_name_wrappable"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseThemeNoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Login Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="xxxxxxxx"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseThemeNoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
    </activity>
    <!-- Matter List/Main Activity ************ -->
    <activity
        android:name="xxxxx"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:label="My Matters"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
    </activity>
    <!-- Settings Login Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="xxxxx"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:label="Login"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
    </activity>
    <!-- Settings Display Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="xxxxxx"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:label="Display"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
    </activity>
     <!-- Settings Advanced Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="xxxxx"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:label="Advanced"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
    </activity>
    <!-- Settings Change Password Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="xxxxxxx"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:label="Change Password"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
    </activity>
    <!-- Matter Details Activity -->
    <activity
         android:name="xxxxxx"
         android:theme="@style/AppBaseThemeNoActionBarWhite"
         android:parentActivityName="xxxxxxxx "
         android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
         android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    </activity>
    <!-- Matter Tab Fragment Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="xxxxxxx"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
    </activity>
    <!-- Info Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="xxxxxx"
        android:label="Info &amp; Help"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
    </activity>
    <!-- Document Details Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="xxxxxx"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
    </activity>
    <!-- Mark As Client Document Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="xxxxxx"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
    </activity>
    <!-- Email Document Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="xxxxxxx"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
    </activity>
    <!-- Print Dialog Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="xxxxx"
        android:label="Google Cloud Print"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
    </activity>
    <!-- Write Messages Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="xxxxx"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:label="New Messages"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
    </activity>
    <!-- About Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="xxxxx"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseThemeNoActionBarWhite"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
    </activity>
    <!-- Push Notification Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="xxxxx"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:label="@string/push_noti"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
    </activity>

    <!-- For Google Cloud Messaging -->
    <!-- Receiver for Message from GCM -->
    <receiver
        android:name="xxxx"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

           <category android:name="xxxxxxx" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have two different versions of your app installed (i.e., one from the store and one from Android Studio, with a different package name)? Look in the app list under Settings.

Comment: thanks Ted. if i delete the app on the test device to get a "clean slate" - then go to Settings -> Application Manager, I confirm that I dont see any reference at all to the app. Then, if I just download from the Play Store, i see 2 icons. I'm wondering whether its worth waiting until the next app update to the Play Store (next few weeks) to see if the issue goes away (since its fine via installs from Android Studio) ? Or is there some other setting/XML file etc. that I should be checking ?

Comment: It might help if you posted the entire manifest.

Comment: yes ive added it to the question above. txs for ur help w/ this.

Comment: hi all, does anyone have any advice on this particular issue ? thanks in advance.