# React native - Use multiple intent-filter in AndroidManifest.xml for branch and splash activity

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am integrating [branch](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/react-native) to my react native mobile app. Before that I had in my AndroidManifest.xml file the package [react-native-splash-screen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-splash-screen) in use for the Splash Screen.

In order to integrate branch, I need to use according to their [documentation](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/react-native) the intent-filter in a launcher activity like this in the android manifest.xml file:

```js
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

But this results in two "[apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35883129/why-android-app-icon-showing-twice-after-installing-from-play-store-but-only-onc)" so the app crashes when launching.
When I remove one of the code block above, which I have implemented twice, it crashed on the respective activity executed where the block is removed. So when I select a branch deep link and the block is not in the branch launch activity the app crashes and when I launch the app normally and the block is not in the splash activity the app crashes. So I am wondering if somebody has a solution to my problem. Thanks for the help.

And here is my whole android manifest file:

```js
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="XXXX">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <!-- required for react-native-share base64 sharing -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    // get the network state
    <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    // get the wifi state
    <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application
            android:name=".MainApplication"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- Launcher Activity to handle incoming Branch intents -->
        <activity
                android:name=".LauncherActivity"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


            <!-- Branch URI Scheme -->
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- If utilizing $deeplink_path please explicitly declare your hosts, or utilize a wildcard(*) -->
                <data android:scheme="XXXX" android:host="open" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Branch App Links - Live App -->
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="XXXX" />
                <!-- example-alternate domain is required for App Links when the Journeys/Web SDK and Deepviews are used inside your website.  -->
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="XXXX" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Branch App Links - Test App -->
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="vc5z8.app.link" />
                <!-- example-alternate domain is required for App Links when the Journeys/Web SDK and Deepviews are used inside your website.  -->
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="XXXX" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Branch init -->
        <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="XXXX" />
        <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey.test" android:value="XXXX" />
        <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="false" />     <!-- Set to true to use Branch_Test_Key (useful when simulating installs and/or switching between debug and production flavors) -->

        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
                android:value="XXXX"/>

        <!-- Add this SplashActivity -->
        <activity
                android:name=".SplashActivity"
                android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.raygun.raygun4android.services.CrashReportingPostService"
                 android:exported="false"
                 android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
                 android:process=":crashreportingpostservice"/>

        <service android:name="com.raygun.raygun4android.services.RUMPostService"
                 android:exported="false"
                 android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
                 android:process=":rumpostservice" />
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:exported="true"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```